# Postgres query to count only the last three records to each customer without to check the date

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a  PostgreSQL query where i need to check only the last three records to each customer and count how many records each costumer had with value = 0.

Example:
Table of Customers:

| Key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Peter |
| 3 | Mike |

| key | Date | Customer | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-02-07 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2012-02-08 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2012-02-09 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2012-03-07 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2012-04-07 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 2012-07-09 | 2 | 0 |
| 7 | 2012-04-08 | 3 | 0 |
| 8 | 2012-04-08 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 2012-04-09 | 3 | 0 |

I need it:

| Costumer | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |

After to get this result i need to take only the customers with count >= 3

| Costumer | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |

I tried to do it using Rank() function but no way..
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

First add record numbers `rn` per customer (the inner `ti` sub-query) then select the count of records `cnt` that have `rn <= 3` per customer (the outer `tx` sub-query) and finally select those with `cnt >= 3`. Btw `cnt` can not be greater than 3.

```sql
select * from 
(
  select customer, count(*) cnt
  from 
  (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by customer order by dt desc) rn 
    from the_table
  ) ti
  where value = 0 and rn <= 3 -- last 3 records  only
  group by customer
) tx where cnt >= 3;
```

Comment: thank you so much about your help!

this is my data query, could you help me to let using your example to check here?:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select destinatarios.nome, intervalo, log_apps.created_at, count(log_apps.id) from log_apps 
inner join emprestimos on log_apps.emprestimo_id = emprestimos.id
inner join destinatarios on emprestimos.destinatario_id = destinatarios.id
where valor = 0 
and intervalo = 1
group by destinatarios.nome, intervalo, log_apps.created_at

order by destinatarios.nome desc